# How to setup polymorphic classes and recursion with C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, polymorphism

A base class, `VideoContainer`, contains a list of `VideoContainers`.

The properties in VideoContainer are common to three other classes of which there are three:

- `Layout`
- `Perspective`
- `Source`

Each of these classes have different properties, and should fit inside the `VideoContainers` collection.

```
/// <summary>
/// Video container
/// </summary>
public class VideoContainer<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Container ID
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Type of container - {Layout, Perspective, SourceContainer}
    /// 
    /// This is usually set by the instantiated class.
    /// </summary>
    public ContainerTypes ContainerType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parent ID
    /// </summary>
    public VideoContainerIdentifier ParentObject { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of container
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Details about the physical location of this container
    /// </summary>
    public LocationDefinition LocationDefinition { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When container has a tile applied - number of rows of containers within this perspective
    /// </summary>
    public short NumRows { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When container has a tile aplpied - the number of columns of containers within this perspective
    /// </summary>
    public short NumColumns { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// List of containers
    /// </summary>
    public IList<VideoContainer<T>> VideoContainers { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Draw
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        // drawing tasks
    }

}
```

The initial problem was that I couldn't put a Layout (or other class type) inside the VideoContainers collection, as it expects a type of VideoContainer.

So I added `<T>`, hoping but having problems accessing the properties of type `<T>` - which doesn't work.

How can I set this up properly?

**-- UPDATE --**

What I forgot to mention is that the classes all inherit `VideoContainers`.

As per the suggestion below, I created `public interface IVideoContainer<T>`.

The Layout class is now defined as  `public class Layout : IVideoContainer<Layout>` and implements all of the interface's methods:

```
public class Layout : IVideoContainer<Layout>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ctor
    /// </summary>
    public Layout()
    {
        ContainerType = ContainerTypes.Layout;
    }

    public int Id
    {...
```

Problem is in implementing:

```
        var layout = new IVideoContainer<Layout>
            {
                Id = 1,
                ParentObject = null,
                Name = "Layout Definition 1",
                LocationDefinition = new LocationDefinition
                    {
                        TopLeftX = 0,
                        TopLeftY = 0,
                        WidthPixels = 1000,
                        HeightPixels = 1000
                    },
                NumRows = 20,
                NumColumns = 20,
                VideoContainers = new List<Perspective>
                    {
                        new IVideoContainer<Perspective>
                        {
                            Id = 10, ...
```

**-- Update 2 --**

I now have:

```
/// <summary>
/// VideoContainer
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class VideoContainer<T> : IVideoContainer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ContainerTypes ContainerType { get; set; }
    public VideoContainerIdentifier ParentObject { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LocationDefinition LocationDefinition { get; set; }
    public short NumRows { get; set; }
    public short NumColumns { get; set; }
    public IList<IVideoContainer> VideoContainers { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is that SourceContainer contains new properties, which I cannot access - `CctvId` and `StreamUri`:

```
VideoContainers = new List<VideoContainer<SourceContainer>>
    {
        new VideoContainer<SourceContainer>
            {
                Id = 20,
                ParentObject = new VideoContainerIdentifier
                    {
                        Id = 10,
                        ContainerType = ContainerTypes.Perspective
                    },
                ContainerType = ContainerTypes.SourceContainer,
                CctvId = new Guid(),
                StreamUri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/somestream"),
                LocationDefinition = new LocationDefinition     // TODO: verify that {x,y} are relative to the perspective
                    {
                        TopLeftX = 0,
                        TopLeftY = 0,
                        WidthPixels = 10,
                        HeightPixels = 10                                                        
                    }

            },
```

SourceContainer class:

```
public class SourceContainer : IVideoContainer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// the URI of the stream for this source
    /// </summary>
    public Uri StreamUri { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// the descriptive name of this source
    /// </summary>
    //public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// optional device id for this source
    /// </summary>
    public Guid? CctvId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ctor
    /// </summary>
    public SourceContainer()
    {
        ContainerType = ContainerTypes.SourceContainer;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ContainerTypes ContainerType { get; set; }
    public VideoContainerIdentifier ParentObject { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LocationDefinition LocationDefinition { get; set; }
    public short NumRows { get; set; }
    public short NumColumns { get; set; }
    public IList<IVideoContainer> VideoContainers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an Interface that collects the common properties, have your three classes inherit from it, and then cast your T to the Interface to access the properties.

```
public class VideoContainer: IVideoContainer
{
    public List<IVideoContainer> Children { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to access properties specific to the object you're storing in the List, just cast it to the original object:

```
var child = Children.First();
var type = m.GetType();
if(type.Name == "ChildClass")
{
    var container = (ChildClass)child;
    // Now you can access VideoContainer specific properties in `container`.
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I made public interface IVideoContainer<T> and what I forgot to mention above is that the classes do inherit from VideoContainer.  Updated above based on your suggestion, but not sure if it is implemented correctly.

Comment: Why is the generic in there?  `IVideoContainer` just needs to have all of your common properties; you don't need an `IVideoContainer<T>`, just a `VideoContainer<T>`.

Comment: Alright, I removed the generic from IVideoContainer, but what about the List of VideoContainers within?  Not sure where the VideoContainer<t> fits in.

Comment: Actually, you may not need the generic at all.  You already have a recursive list within `VideoContainer`.  If you make that a list of `IVideoContainer`, it will hold anything that inherits the interface.  Hold on, I'll add some code.

Comment: Great... we were on the same page on that.  I did implement that property, however, as updated above (Update 2), I can't access the "injected" properties of of SourceContainer.

Comment: Just added the SourceContainer class for reference.

Comment: Ok... but the issue is how to set the properties that are not a part of `VideoContainer` but a part of one of the child classes, when adding that class to the `List<IVideoContainer>`?

Comment: You have to cast it to the specific type of that child class to set those properties.  You do that by determining what the type is by calling `TypeOf()`, and then casting to that specific type.  See the update I made to my code above.